# Cannot access data from database using specific id

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymysql

```
import pymysql
import os

conn =pymysql.connect(host='localhost',database='pyp',user='root',password='')
a = conn.cursor()
h= raw_input('enter your id')
sql='SELECT * from report WHERE Id = h'
a.execute(sql)
data=a.fetchall()

print(data)
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is that your query is:

```
SELECT * from report WHERE Id = h
```

So it interprets `h` as a *MySQL column `h`* (which probably does not even exists)

Python will not automagically replace `h` with the variable `h` unless you specify that.

You can solve this by using:

```
sql='SELECT * from report WHERE Id = %s'
a.execute(sql,(h,))
```

So you specify a parameter with `%s` and then you call `.execute(..)` with the (list of) values.